# What indexed view capabilities does Azure SQL Database have?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, materialized-view

Does Azure SQL Database support indexed views? Does it support automatic indexed view matching without `NOEXPAND`? Does the answer depend on the pricing tier?

I was unable to find definitive answers to these questions. The [feature differences guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/) does not mention indexed views.

The [indexed view documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) does not contain the word "Azure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just searching for an answer to this and I found an [MSDN blog entry from 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/09/04/does-azure-sql-db-support-automatic-indexed-views/) that suggests that Azure SQL does support indexed view matching and may (in at least some circumstances) use indexed views without `NOEXPAND`. From the linked article:

> YES,The code proves that the  Azure SQL supports automatic use of indexed views without specifying the NOEXPAND hint.

The blog entry also provides a code example that the author uses to support their assertion. I won't reproduce it here but check out the article at: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/09/04/does-azure-sql-db-support-automatic-indexed-views/

Answer (score 0):

Just don't get disappointed when you try to assert your thinking onto the database - and it doesn't agree!

I have an indexed view right now where a complex query (which does not mention the view by name) was able to figure out that a nonclustered index on the view would work perfectly - I was impressed.

But a second nonclustered index on the same view couldn't be triggered without NOEXPAND even though I only queried and SELECT-ed a single column from the view AND mentioned the view by name!

So yes it can work in some very impressive ways - but can also fail in some super simple ways.

I read somewhere that sometimes it 'doesn't even bother to check if the indexed view is more efficient' if it determines that expanding can be good enough!